# Select nodes and edges form networkx graph with attributes

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, networkx

I've just started doing graphs in networkx and I want to follow the evolution of a graph in time: how it changed, what nodes/edges are in the graph at a specified time t.

Here is my code:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_node(1,id=1000,since='December 2008')
G.add_node(2,id=2000,since='December 2008')
G.add_node(3,id=3000,since='January 2010')
G.add_node(4,id=2000,since='December 2016')
G.add_edge(1,2,since='December 2008')
G.add_edge(1,3,since='February 2010')
G.add_edge(2,3,since='March 2014')
G.add_edge(2,4,since='April 2017')
nx.draw_spectral(G,with_labels=True,node_size=3000)
plt.show()
```

This shows the graph with all the nodes and edges.

So, my question is:

How to design a time-based filter that will extract only the relevant nodes/edges on my graph G graph at time t, say for example 'July 2014'. When it is done, how do I update the graph with matplotlib?

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 19):

You may select nodes by conditions with list comprehension with `G.nodes()` method:

```
selected_nodes = [n for n,v in G.nodes(data=True) if v['since'] == 'December 2008']  
print (selected_nodes)
```

Out: `[1, 2]`

To select edges use `G.edges_iter` or `G.edges` methods:

```
selected_edges = [(u,v) for u,v,e in G.edges(data=True) if e['since'] == 'December 2008']
print (selected_edges)
```

Out: `[(1, 2)]`

To plot selected nodes call `G.subgraph()`

```
H = G.subgraph(selected_nodes)
nx.draw(H,with_labels=True,node_size=3000)
```

To plot selected edges with attributes you may construct new graph:

```
H = nx.Graph(((u, v, e) for u,v,e in G.edges(data=True) if e['since'] == 'December 2008'))
nx.draw(H,with_labels=True,node_size=3000)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: A better way to draw the subgraphs would be to plot `G`, but with `nodelist` and `edgelist` specified in the `draw` command.  Successive calls with specified `pos`  and `nodecolor` values would allow to plot several parts of the graph on the same axes but in different colors.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Initially, I was thinking about doing a function that takes as parameter: the graph, a date range (before and after) and then use filter. But, your proposition is also ok.

Comment: In fact, what I had in mind initially was to get the state of the graph in a date range. When I consider for example "March 2014", it means the graph from date T0 to "March 2014". I think that the proposition of "Serenity" only gives a snapshot at a date but not what happens before

Comment: To slice edge list, you can do list(G.edges)[0:20:None].

Comment: @jezzy you can easily do the date range you describe above by changing the `==` in the filter to a `<=` check of some sort (which would require a structured data type that has a notion of ordering, rather than the string attributes you use in your question).