# How to obtain a subset of nodes in NetworkX?

Tags: python, dictionary, networkx, graph-theory

I've been working on a multipartite layout graph with NetworkX. The graph looks something like this:

[image]

Each node on my graph has a `'trajectory'` attribute and a `'layer'` attribute. The layer indicates which column the node belongs to.

An example of the first two columns of nodes is shown:

```
[('0.0', {'layer': 0, 'trajectory': 0}), ('1.0', {'layer': 0, 'trajectory': 1}), ('2.0', {'layer': 0, 'trajectory': 2}), ('3.0', {'layer': 0, 'trajectory': 3}), ('4.0', {'layer': 0, 'trajectory': 4}), ('5.0', {'layer': 0, 'trajectory': 5}), ('6.0', {'layer': 0, 'trajectory': 6}), ('7.0', {'layer': 0, 'trajectory': 7}), ('8.0', {'layer': 0, 'trajectory': 8}), ('9.0', {'layer': 0, 'trajectory': 9}), ('10.0', {'layer': 0, 'trajectory': 10}), ('11.0', {'layer': 0, 'trajectory': 11}), ('12.0', {'layer': 0, 'trajectory': 12}), ('13.0', {'layer': 0, 'trajectory': 13}), ('14.0', {'layer': 0, 'trajectory': 14}), ('0.1', {'layer': 1, 'trajectory': 0}), ('1.1', {'layer': 1, 'trajectory': 1}), ('2.1', {'layer': 1, 'trajectory': 2}), ('3.1', {'layer': 1, 'trajectory': 3}), ('4.1', {'layer': 1, 'trajectory': 4}), ('5.1', {'layer': 1, 'trajectory': 5}), ('6.1', {'layer': 1, 'trajectory': 6}), ('7.1', {'layer': 1, 'trajectory': 7}), ('8.1', {'layer': 1, 'trajectory': 8}), ('9.1', {'layer': 1, 'trajectory': 9}), ('10.1', {'layer': 1, 'trajectory': 10}), ('11.1', {'layer': 1, 'trajectory': 11}), ('12.1', {'layer': 1, 'trajectory': 12}), ('13.1', {'layer': 1, 'trajectory': 13}), ('14.1', {'layer': 1, 'trajectory': 14}), ('15.1', {'layer': 1, 'trajectory': '15'})]
```

I need to retrieve all the nodes in a specific column. If I were to pick the 2nd column then to access it I could do:

```py
column = 2
for nodename, nodeattrs in G.nodes(data=True):
    if nodeattrs['layer'] == column:
        print('I am a node in the column: ' + str(column))
        # I do more stuff here
```

I think that is not a very efficient nor elegant way to solve my issue since I have to check every node in the graph. My graph will have thousands of columns, which makes me believe there has to be a way of obtaining the subset of nodes I want without having to check if each node has the specified layer or not.

Is there a better way to implement this?

EDIT: I found an answer to my question here:

[Select nodes and edges form networkx graph with attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45350222/select-nodes-and-edges-form-networkx-graph-with-attributes)

In my case it would be something along the lines:

```py
dict( (n,d['layer']) for n,d in G.nodes().items() if d['layer'] == 2)
```

Which returns a dictionary I can save.

Comment: When you create the graph, can you not also make a dictionary that maps layers to nodes? Having a single data structure for both mappings (node -> layer, and hence implicitly layer -> node) seems sub-optimal here.

Comment: That may actually work. I have to test it because my actual implementation is not my proudest code. Will be back!

Comment: For anyone wondering I found a similar question to mine in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45350222/select-nodes-and-edges-form-networkx-graph-with-attributes